# Grouped Items Always Show As Salable

Tags: magento2, products

I am trying to remove prices for certain products in a group from being displayed. I created an interceptor with the **afterIsSalable** method to check for my condition and return false if met.

This works fine mostly however within `grouped.phtml` which shows all the grouped prices on the product view page the `$_item->isSalable()` returns **true** (when it should return **false** for this case).

If I grab the product like below it correctly returns **false** however:

```
    //test just to grab the product from the item id and check value:
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $_producttest = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId());
    echo "DISP:" . $_producttest->isSalable(); //RETURNS FALSE
```

Compared with:

```
$_item->isSalable(); //RETURNS TRUE
```

Why would this be working like this?

Answer (score 0):

The function **`getAssociatedProducts()`** adds only a select few attributes to the collection. I created a preference for the `Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped` class and then modified **`getAssociatedProducts()`** to add the '`msrp_display_actual_price_type`' attribute to the collection like below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
  public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
  {
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id', 'msrp_display_actual_price_type']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
  }
}
```